# Check if every id has an existing object in array

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I would like to check if there is an existing object for every id of an array.

```
const ids = [ 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i', 'fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p' ]
const target = [
  { _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i' },
  { _id: 'Qt5X8pfbcJMn6ixxn' },
]
```

In this example I would like to get `false`, as the second ID (fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p) is not existing.

This should return `true`:

```
const ids = [ 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i', 'fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p' ]
const target = [
  { _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i' },
  { _id: 'Qt5X8pfbcJMn6ixxn' },
  { _id: 'fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p' },
]
```

This is what I've tried:

```
ids.every(id => target.find(element => element._id === id))
```

Comment: Now after your edit, your code would work too.

Comment: @baao I just got it after writing the post. As There is a answer postet I can't delete the post.

Comment: Do you want to accept my answer or do you want me to delete my answer? You should really use some though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're pretty close, you need to pass a function instead of an object to `find` though - and I'd recommend to use [`some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) instead of `find` if you only want to know about if it exists, rather than you need the object in return.

```js
const ids = [ 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i', 'fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p' ]
const target = [
  { _id: 'xxnQt5X8pfbcJMn6i' },
  { _id: 'Qt5X8pfbcJMn6ixxn' },
  { _id: 'fbcJMn6ixxnQt5X8p' },
]

const allIn = ids.every(id => target.some(({_id}) => id === _id));
console.log(allIn);
```

Answer (score 1):

With a lot of entries, it might be faster to use a Set (so we get `O(n + m)` instead of `O(n * m)`) :

```
const idSet = new Set(target.map(el => el._id));
const result = ids.every(id => idSet.has(id));
```

Answer (score 0):

Since every is itself a checker method it's return `true` or `false` through the  provided function. So you can simply return `false`:

`const res = const res = ids.every(id => target._id === id);
console.log(res);`

or `true`:

`const res = ids.every(id => target._id !== id);
console.log(res);`